# Dockerizing Spring Boot Application

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with the below Dockerfile.

```
FROM docker.com/base/jdk1.8:latest

MAINTAINER Application Engineering [ https://docker.com/ ]

RUN mkdir -p /opt/docker/svc

COPY application/weather-service.war /opt/docker/svc/

CMD java -jar /opt/docker/svc/weather-service.war --spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties -Dlogging.config=/conf/logback.xml
```

I need 20 different properties for my application. I have 10 properties in application.properties and want to pass the rest thru env variable. The 10 properties from the application.properties file works fine, but the env variable is not working as expected.

Also, is it possible to pass few of them using "-D" like -Dtest.name=test?

Cant we have mix of all?

Thanks

Comment: how did you add the environment vars

Comment: -e TEST_NAME=test

Comment: You can add the env  in docker file like ENV TESTNAME=test see if it works

Comment: Yes, it works. But, I want to pass it using -e.

Comment: then you will have to run the java command after the image is up and running. or use docker compose to make it easier

Answer (score 0):

use docker-compose to add in your env var for runtime

```js
 api:
    image: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
       - TEST=test
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
    entrypoint: /bin/bash -c "java -jar /opt/docker/svc/weather-service.war --spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties -Dlogging.config=/conf/logback.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method would be use an environment-file. The java properties file usually are in a similar format. If not, you'll have to make some adjustments to avoid duplication.

```
 api:
    image: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
       - TEST=test
    env_file: <relative path to environment file>
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
    entrypoint: /bin/bash -c "java -jar /opt/docker/svc/weather-service.war --spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties -Dlogging.config=/conf/logback.xml"
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file